# Why is this application being closed?

Tags: c, linux, timeout, signals, wsl-2

Does handling signals make the application close in anyway? my goal is to do some action when time run out but get stuck in the loop, until the user enter q or EOF is found but for some reason as soon the singal is received, the application seem to not execute the loop at all just print     printf("returning from main!!\n"); and exit from the application. What am I misisng? how do i fix that?

here's the full code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void thread_signal_handler(int signal)
{
    // Thread's time slice has run out, switch to another thread
    // ...
    printf("time run out!!!\n");
}

int main()
{
    // Set up the signal handler for the thread's time slice
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = thread_signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

    // Set up the timer for the thread's time slice
    struct itimerval timer;
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        int ch = getchar();
        if(ch == 'q' || ch == EOF) break;
    }
    printf("returning from main!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calling `printf` in a signal handler is not safe, even though it often works.

Comment: Sadly, [`setitimer` is obsolescent](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html#tag_16_202_07). You may wish to consider [`timer_settime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_settime.html), instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal handler is getting fired while `getchar` is waiting for user input.

After the signal handler returns, `getchar` returns EOF and `errno` is set to `EINTR`, indicating that the call was interrupted.  This causes your loop to exit.

Answer (score 2):

> If a read error occurs, the error
> indicator for the stream shall be set, getchar() shall return EOF,
> and shall set errno to indicate the error.

The `getchar()` function shall fail if data needs to be read and:

> EINTR
>
> The read operation was terminated due to the receipt of a
> signal, and no data was transferred.

After the signal handler completes, execution returns to the point right where the signal interrupted it. `getchar()` then returns `EOF` because it was interrupted by a signal, and sets `errno` to `EINTR`, which causes the `while` loop to exit.

That being said, your code simply invokes undefined behaviour because `printf()` is async-signal-unsafe, i.e. it can't be called safely inside a signal handler. (Neither in the C standard, nor the POSIX standard).

Though, the POSIX standard does define the `write()` syscall to be async-signal-safe that can be used instead of `printf()`:

```
write (STDOUT_FILENO, "time run out!!!\n", 17);
```